# GeoFire with react native

Tags: react-native, geofire

I'm trying to store the data along with location info in the firebase real-time database. So I came across a package name geofire and try to use it in my react native project but I didn't find any documentation and tutorial for geofire with react native. Any suggestion from where I can learn the use of geofire will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To my knowledge, you should be able to just import the package into your JavaScript file as a module, then follow the vanilla js instructions. React uses es6, which just uses import/export statements.

Comment: @NanoAdam thanks for your reply. Do I need any extra config to setup geofire in my react native project?

Comment: not all. Just use npm install geofire and get started. The only difference should be that you have access to state and all with React. You could just write vanilla js and get away with it.